# Linear thumbwheel potentiometer obsolete?

Tags: potentiometer, linear

I am trying to find a possibly obsolete linear thumbwheel potentiometer, like the type used in old radios. There seem to be plenty of logarithmic pots around. I can find linear but they are marked as "end of life". Are these linear pots obsolete?

Comment: What is your intended use? Log pots are generally required for volume control.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but please note that direct shopping questions will result in fairly prompt closure of your question as per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as you have found out already. If you  edit your question with a photo of the pots and ask instead if anyone knows what the type name is then your question may be reopened.

Comment: PWM control of a 555 timer.

Comment: They're still made.. not necessarily easy to buy in small quantity through distribution.

Comment: Check the piano / synth modulation wheels